# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} H_m(x)H_n(x)dx$

Tags: applications, hermite-polynomials

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} H_m(x)H_n(x)dx=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & m \neq n\\ 
 2^n n! \sqrt{\pi},& m = n
\end{matrix}\right.$

Thats a Hermite polynomials. I need a hint, i really didn't get that at all.

Comment: This is the orthogonality property of Hermite polynomials. What definition of the Hermite polynomials do you have?

Comment: Thats like a solving;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjqZdj8VBCM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPhy_2EiU1o
I need steps...

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question: What definition of Hermite polynomials are you starting from? They can be defined via their generating function, Rodrigues formula, recurrence relations, or differential equation---or, indeed, the orthogonality condition itself. Each of those are a different but equivalent starting point. So unless you tell us which one you're using, we can't help.

Comment: @Semiclassical i want to use Rodrigues formula.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.